# Need Clarification in Interface concept in JAVA

Tags: java, interface

I am learning Java Programming and I am a beginner. I am learning Interfaces now. I came across the below two simple examples and I have doubt in those

**Program1**

```
public interface Callback {
    void callback(int param);
}

class Client implements Callback {
    // Implement Callback's interface
    public void callback(int p) {
        System.out.println("callback called with " + p);
    }

    void nonIfaceMeth() {
        System.out.println("Classes that implement interfaces " +
            "may also define other members, too.");
    }
}

class TestIface {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Callback c = new Client();
        c.callback(42);
        // c.nonIfaceMeth();
    }
}
```

**Program 2**

```
class Client implements Callback {
    // Implement Callback's interface
    public void callback(int p) {
        System.out.println("callback called with " + p);
    }

    void nonIfaceMeth() {
        System.out.println("Classes that implement interfaces " +
            "may also define other members, too.");
    }
}

class TestIface {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Client c = new Client();
        c.callback(42);
    }
}
```

Both **Program1** and **Program2** give the same output.

In **Program1**, **variable c** is declared to be of the interface type and in **Program2**, **variable c** is declared to be of the Class type.

My doubt is what is the difference between these two programs and what are the advantages of creating a Interface type variable ?

Kindly help me t understand the concept. TIA

Comment: Read up on polymorphism...

Comment: it seems this question is about polymorphism, rather than interfaces. In one example, it might be declared as a Callback, but it is initialized as a Client type.

Comment: Ryan J - I want the difference between these two statements "Callback c = new Client();" and "Client c = new Client();" and what are the advantages of creating a Interface type variable ?

Comment: The difference is: if you say Client client, you'll have access to all the methods of Client, while when you declare it as a Callback, you'll be limited to the methods defined in Callback. The reason: you can implement a method that should be able to handle all implementations of Callback that will ever be created, without being able to know what methods they have, just knowing they will provide an implementation for the methods defined in the interface.

Comment: Not sure Why I am getting downvotes. I am a beginner and now only im starting learning.  No one will have experience in asking questions in stack over flow by birth.

Comment: Padmanabhan: I haven't downvoted, but I do think I know why some did. This can be easily answered by reading the first chapters of a(ny) good textbook on Java or the official tutorials/documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to keep it short as web is full explainaions on interfaces.

Interface is a contract. Many classes can implement an interface. Using interface is one way to loosly couple your code components.

> In Program1, variable c is declared to be of the interface type

This means that any implementation of this interface can be taken to create a concrete object and your code should not break.

> and in Program2, variable c is declared to be of the Class type.

This means that you have to change your code to use right class every time you need to use a different implementation. Your code is very cohesive.

It will make more sense when you start studing things like dependency injection or factory pattern etc. Also helpful in unit testing.

---

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment

> I want the difference between these two statements "Callback c = new
>   Client();" and "Client c = new Client();"

It is very conceptual at the moment but `Callback c = new Client()` but allows you to change the type of your varible `C`at any time. Lets say there is an other implementation `ImportantClient` in your code where interface is used to declare the variable you can at any time change it to `c = new ImportantClient()`. However you can not do that if you are using `Client c = new Client();`

Answer (score 1):

One reason to use an interface is when you want to reduce dependencies between classes or components.

If you have a method that can take an interface as a parameter, for example:

```
public int countItems(List myList) { ... }
```

... then you are able to pass in any object whose class implements the `List` interface, without have that dependency hard coded in the method.

In your case, using the interface `Callback` enables other classes to be used in the code, if they implement the `Callback` interface.

Another reason is that it buys you flexibility in choice of concrete class. If you create the object and keep a reference to the interface, it restricts you to only interact with the object through the interface's methods. This means that in future, you could change which concrete class you construct, and as long as it implements the interface, your code will continue to work without requiring modification.

Comment: Jason - I can understand the What is the use of Interface.  My doubt is, In program1, whay we are declaring the variable as a Interface Type?  We can get the output using the Class type Variable as in Program2 right. What is the use of declaring the variable as Interface type and assigned an instance of Client (class) ?

Answer (score 1):

In its most common form, an interface is a group of related methods with empty bodies. A bicycle's behavior, if specified as an interface, might appear as follows:

```
interface Bicycle {

    //  wheel revolutions per minute
    void changeCadence(int newValue);

    void changeGear(int newValue);

    void speedUp(int increment);

    void applyBrakes(int decrement);
}
```

[Reference : Oracle JAVA Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

[Go through : Using an Interface as a Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117244/need-clarification-in-interface-concept-in-java)

Comment: @Padmanabhan-Vijay : Go through "Using an Interface as a Type" link in Answer for more clarification

Answer (score 1):

Both are same in your case when saying

```
Client c = new Client();
```

Here actually you are just creating an object of a client. And calling a method of the `class Client`.

And when you say

```
Callback c = new Client();
```

You are just creating a reference of type `CallBack` but at runtime an `Object` of `Client` is being created. So both are same in your case.